# Why doesn't my pyqt5's appendPlainText work?

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is my initial code. I want it to print a desired text in the plain text box but it doesn't. I have tried running the code without any socket programming and it did work but when I added the sockets, the program just says not responding. The line where there is an error is bold (** **). And your help is greatly appreciated.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog
from socket import *
import socket
from threading import Thread

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.MainWindow = MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(251, 335)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.BigBox = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.BigBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 231, 211))
        self.BigBox.setObjectName("BigBox")
        self.BigBox.setPlainText("")

        self.SmallBox = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.SmallBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 231, 31))
        self.SmallBox.setObjectName("SmallBox")
        self.SmallBox.setPlainText("")

        self.hostButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.hostButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 270, 75, 23))
        self.hostButton.setObjectName("hostButton")

        self.submitButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.submitButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 270, 75, 23))
        self.submitButton.setObjectName("submitButton")

        self.connectButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.connectButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 270, 75, 23))
        self.connectButton.setObjectName("connectButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.hostButton.clicked.connect(self.popForHost)
        self.connectButton.clicked.connect(self.popForConnect)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Chat Room"))
        self.hostButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Host"))
        self.submitButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Submit"))
        self.connectButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect"))

    def popForHost(self):
        self.port ,y = QInputDialog.getText(self.MainWindow, "Host Options", "Enter The Port: ")
        if y == True:
            self.serverForHost()

    def popForConnect(self):
        self.IP ,y = QInputDialog.getText(self.MainWindow, "Connect Options", "Enter The IP: ")
        self.port2 ,b = QInputDialog.getText(self.MainWindow, "Connect Options", "Enter The Port: ")
        if y == True and b == True:
            self.serverForConnect()

    def serverForHost(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

        self.s.bind(('', int(self.port)))
        ** self.BigBox.appendPlainText("Hello") **
        self.s.listen(1) #Max of one connection
        self.conn,self.addr = self.s.accept() #Accept conn
        print("[+] Connected: "+str(self.addr[0])+ ' Port: '+str(self.addr[1]))
        print(self.conn.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8"))
        
        t1 = Thread(target=self.hostThread)
        t1.start()

    def serverForConnect(self):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

        self.s.connect((self.IP, int(self.port2)))
        self.s.send(str.encode("[+] Connection Established"))

        t2 = Thread(target=self.connectThread)
        t2.start()
        
    def hostThread(self):
        while 1:
            command = input("["+str(self.IPAddr)+']: ')
            self.conn.send(bytes(command, 'UTF-8'))
            data = self.conn.recv(1024).decode()
            print("["+str(self.addr[0])+"]: " +data)

    def connectThread(self):
        while 1:
            data = self.s.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
            print("["+str(self.IP)+"]: "+data)
            command = input("["+str(self.IPAddr)+"]: ")
            self.s.send(bytes(command, "UTF-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try to run the program from shell/command prompt and see what is the output.

Comment: all GUIs don't update widget on screen directly when you set changes but after execuiting all code in function - this way it redraws all changes in one moment (instead of redrawing many times for many changes) and this way GUI doesn't blink so much. But your function uses `accept()` to wait for connection so it doesn't end function and GUI can't redraw widgets. It may need some function like `update()` or `refresh()`  (or something similar) to force GUI to redraw widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All GUIs don't update/readraw widget on directly when you set changes but after execuiting all code in your function. This way it redraws all changes in one moment (instead of redrawing widgets many times for many changes) and this way GUI doesn't blink so much.

But your function uses `accept()` to wait for connection so it doesn't end function and GUI can't redraw widgets.

Using `repaint()` you can force GUI to redraw widget at once.

```
    self.BigBox.appendPlainText("Hello")
    self.BigBox.repaint()
```